# how to implement a help function with javascript and php?

Tags: php, javascript, html

On a page (i.e mypage.html) I display a menu. One button of this menu shall call a contextual help.

```
<a href="#" onclick="(helpme())">Help</a>
```

The javascript helpme function calls a php module:

```
function helpme() {document.location="help.php";}
```

The help.php, according to the context, shall open into a NEW browser window the content of another php module :

```
 switch ( $_SESSION['function']  )
    {
        case 'central':
            echo '<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">window.open("/help/help_central.php","help", "height=200, width=200, top=100, left=500, menubar=0, toolbar=0, location=0, status=0");</script>'; 
            break;
```

etc...

Unfortunately this complicate solution doesn't work: the new window is displayed with the correct text but mypage.html is replaced by help.php !
Could you suggest a correction or an easier way to implement a help ?

Comment: Why not use the target attribute of the anchor and forget the javascript all together?

`<a href="help.php" target="_blank">Help me!</a>`

Comment: Can you use jquery libraries like colorbox? http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox

Comment: Also it is window.location and spaces should be avoided in parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `a` tag like this:

```
<a href="help.php" target="_blank">Help</a>
```

As the javascript function does nothing but send the user to there it's not needed to do with js.

**EDIT**

If you want a popup window you can use something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function newPopup(url) {
        popupWindow = window.open(url,'popUpWindow','height=700,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes');
    }
</script>

<a onClick="newPopup('http://www.mydomain.com/example/help.php');">Help me</a>
```

Comment: This solution display help.php instead of mypage.html: nothing solved !

Comment: if you add `target="_blank"` to the `a` tag it WILL open in a new browser tab if the browser supports it.

Comment: I test with FF but I want a global solution ! I don't want a new browser tab: I want mypage.html in one browser window AND help_central.php (accord. to the context) in another browser window !!

Comment: Ok i added a way to open a popup window. Is that more like what you want?

Comment: not yet: two popups are opened: help.php and help_central.php. Good news: mypage.html is staying opened because you suppressed href.

Comment: help.php shall call help_help_central.php by the following command:  header("Location:/help/help_central.php"). Now I have one popup and my mypage.html with the dragon112 proposition. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just something like this?

```
<a target="_blank" href="help.php?#monster">Help on mosters</a>
```

Comment: The problem is not to know the context but to display mypage.html and the help in another window browser.